# Laravel - Auth Session not expiring after browser close

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4, xampp

I am having a problem about sessions, or cookies, I didn't understand the reason.

I log on to my site with `Auth::attempt($userdata, false)`, which means Laravel should not remember my login, but it remembers whether I use true or false in attempt function.

in `app/config/session.php`, variables are determined as

```
'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => true,
```

Also, when I log in with `Auth::attempt($userdata, true)`, `'Auth::viaRemember()'` function returns `false`.

**Edit:** Question solved. Cause of the problem is Chrome. See my answer for detailed information.

Comment: What are the values of `$userdata`?

Comment: How do you know it is remebered? You can ccheck it by `dd(Auth::viaRemember())` if it returdn false, then you are either not waiting long enough for sessions to expire, our you are using MAMP, it can happen there.

Comment: @lozadaOmr I don't think they are related. I can login and logout. The problem is in the session.

Comment: @delmadord I close my browser and open up again, I'm still logged in. I use XAMMP

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have solved my own question. It appeared that the problem is Chrome's problem. It continues to work in background, so the cookie values do not disappear. I tried my app with firefox and works perfectly.

For more info: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513

Answer (score 11):

It is a desired behavior to be logged in after you re-open the browser.
You can change this in `app/config/session.php` by setting

```
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I do this, I can't login at all.

Comment: Then your problem is definitely somewhere else. What is your sessions `lifetime` set to?

Comment: Update your question with details **HOW** you cannot login, when you change what.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I edited the question. My problem is still there.