# Expire session while closing the browser in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel 5.1 and `expire_on_close` is not working in firefox browser and I am using database as session driver.

My config file is,

```
'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => true,
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: A common problem is that even though you "close" the browser, the process is still running and as thus does not trigger the cookie clear.

Comment: So it will be cleared once system shutdown?

Comment: Try to check if the Firefox process is still running on your system, if so shut it down and test again, if not then this wasn't the problem.

Comment: @Nicklas: Firefox persists session cookies across a process recycle if it is configured to remember the open tabs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Auth Session not expiring after browser close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114267/laravel-auth-session-not-expiring-after-browser-close)