# laravel 5.2 session expire on close not working on crome

Tags: laravel

I have tested it in all other browser it works fine. But in chrome when close the browser it's not logged out,  I have also set value like following in session.php

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

Please let us know i am missing any thing?

Comment: just curious, have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25198438/4648586)? because, laravel only changes cookie lifetime [thru this code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/d1a4f3fc7951c04ff91855511ed8c73b1a98e533/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php#L208) and i don't think its laravel only.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have read this. But this post is of 2014 so in case now if there is any change in it. i would like to know.

Comment: first, tried it in another browser again..? cause, it's specific to chrome (just like those old posts). and looking to laravel's code, that part barely changed from back then (if i'm not wrong).