# Laravel 5 - User not logout after session lifetime

Tags: laravel, session, lifetime

I'm on `Laravel 5.7` and trying to get it so that my session expires and logs me out after 2 minutes.

In my `session.php` file i did:

```
'lifetime' => 2,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

I will then leave my computer for example like 15 minutes, come back, refresh, and I'm still logged in?

Can you tell me why and how to fix it. Many thanks.

---

Ok I've figured it out.

The reason is I'm using Auth::logoutOtherDevices in Login function, and this function automatically generates the remember me cookie.

Thank you guys so much.

Comment: Did you click **remember me** in the login form? That would _keep the user authenticated indefinitely, or until they manually logout._ [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#remembering-users)

Comment: no my login form doesn't have remember me option. Also in my code, I set remember me to false

Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], false)

Comment: Did you modify the login logic at any point? If you did, can you add the updated code? Also, did you log out/log in after changing that? (it shouldn't be required, but still...)

Comment: Or do you have any ajax calls being fired in the background that would keep "refreshing" the session?

Comment: No, I've tried to create new session data, and after 2 minutes that data was gone but the auth is still exist

Comment: Do you have any ajax call on that page that keeps repeating? That would keep the session live

Comment: no I don't have

Answer (score 2):

update .env file

`SESSION_LIFETIME=2`

Comment: Also, don't tick remember me.  By the way, it is `SESSION_LIFETIME` not just lifetime in .env.

Comment: no my login form doesn't have remember me option. Also in my code, I set remember me to false

Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], false)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs the lifetime looks like it is in seconds so the lifetime would be

`SESSION_LIFETIME=120` and not `2`.

---

Edit: Please could you try set the option:

```
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

This will force the session to expire on browse close.

I found a potential answer to your issue here: [Laravel - Auth Session not expiring after browser close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114267/laravel-auth-session-not-expiring-after-browser-close)

It sounds like it could be a chrome problem.

Try your solution on firefox to see if it is a chrome issue.

Have a read of that thread i linked.

Comment: In the `config/session.php`, there is a comment _Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session to be allowed to remain idle before it expires_

Comment: But I still want to know why my app didn't work correctly

Comment: Are you using redis? Because it could be your redis caching the session.

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly on firefox the 'expire_on_close' => true doesn't work. Anyone found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to check with your configurations.
In Session.php set lifetime to your desired time for session expiration.
Also in upgraded versions of laravel session lifetime is not set hard anymore, instead it takes from `.env` file.

You can try below configurations.
In your `config/session.php`

```
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 2),
```

And set below key in your `.env` file

```
SESSION_LIFETIME=2
```